# How to select an entity that have same data as another

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-data-packs

Suppose there are two players on a server: player A and player B. Each player has 2 tamed dogs which therefore have the *Owner* data corresponding to their owner.

What I want to do is teleport player A's first dog to his second, and do the same for Player B.

How can I make sure that each dog teleports to the one who has the same *Owner* data as him, regardless of the number of players (here, there were 2 players for the example) using commands and/or datapacks ?